# How to ensure reproducibility of nlme() function calls?

Tags: r, random-seed, nlme

I recently began using the R package {nlme} to fit non-linear mixed-effects models with random effects. I have discovered that running *exactly the same* nlme() function call (i.e., the same line of code: same data, model, and starting parameters) multiple times may yield different results, in that some attempts will converge while others will not, and even converging models may differ (albeit slightly) in parameter estimates.

This appears to be true even when I call set.seed() immediately before the nlme() call. Here is a reproducible example (within the boundaries of this question!) that calls set.seed(10) and then calls nlme(), repeating this process 100 times (~2 seconds/iteration on my laptop). (It does this within a tryCatch() statement with warnings promoted to errors because, in my limited experience, warnings that ultimately lead to non-convergence cause nlme() to hang for extended periods of time; this classifies them as errors and skips to the next loop iteration.) When I ran this code in a fresh instance of R, 5/100 models converged.

```
library(nlme)

# create df for analysis
reprex_data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                      4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                      10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                      13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
                      15L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
                      20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
                      25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
                      30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
                      34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
                      38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 
                      43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 
                      45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
                      47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
                      51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 
                      55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
                      61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 
                      66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 
                      68L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 
                      73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
                      77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
                      80L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 
                      84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 
                      88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L), x = c(7, 7.33, 2.83, 3.33, 
                                                                4.66, 5.25, 5.58, 6.08, 6.5, 7.08, 4.41, 5.41, 6.25, 0, 0.5, 
                                                                1.66, 2.33, 2.75, 3.66, 4.16, 1.66, 2.75, 3.41, 3.75, 4.33, 4.91, 
                                                                5.5, 6.83, 7.33, 2, 2.33, 2.75, 3.75, 2, 2.58, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.41, 
                                                                2.41, 2.66, 3.08, 3.75, 5, 5.58, 6, 6.41, 6.91, 7.41, 5.33, 5.66, 
                                                                6, 6.66, 3.75, 3.66, 4.33, 1.91, 2.5, 2.91, 3.83, 4.33, 1.25, 
                                                                1.91, 2.25, 3.08, 3.75, 2.91, 7.25, 7.91, 8.33, 5, 5.33, 5.66, 
                                                                0.83, 1.5, 1.83, 2.66, 3.16, 6.91, 7.66, 1.41, 2.08, 2.91, 3.5, 
                                                                3.25, 3.5, 7.16, 5.66, 6.33, 6.58, 7.08, 7.58, 3.83, 4.41, 4.83, 
                                                                5.33, 5.75, 6.25, 2.16, 5.08, 5.25, 5.58, 5.83, 6.25, 6.91, 7.25, 
                                                                7.75, 8.16, 8.66, 6.33, 6.66, 2.16, 2.75, 5.41, 5.66, 4.41, 4.75, 
                                                                5.16, 5.75, 6.83, 7.25, 2.75, 3.41, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 2.33, 
                                                                2.83, 1.5, 4.33, 4.66, 5.08, 5.75, 6.16, 6.66, 2.33, 2.91, 3.25, 
                                                                3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 3.66, 3.91, 4.33, 5.16, 5.5, 1.75, 2.33, 2.66, 
                                                                3.66, 4.16, 0.58, 1.16, 1.58, 2, 2.58, 3.08, 5.66, 6.41, 4.25, 
                                                                4.5, 4.25, 4.41, 3.75, 4.33, 4.83, 5.33, 5.75, 6.16, 9.16, 9.5, 
                                                                4.66, 5.25, 5.66, 6.08, 6.58, 7.16, 3.58, 4.16, 4.5, 5.16, 6.16, 
                                                                6.5, 6.5, 6.08, 6.41, 6.75, 2.16, 2.75, 3.16, 3.58, 4.08, 3.41, 
                                                                5.91, 0.91, 8, 8.33, 8.66, 3.33, 3.25, 3.91, 4.16, 4.66, 5, 5.66, 
                                                                6, 6.5, 0.83, 1.83, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 2.25, 2.83, 3.16, 3.66, 
                                                                3.41, 3.75, 4.16, 4.75, 5.08, 8.16, 4.41, 4.66, 5.08, 6.5, 6.75, 
                                                                7.16, 7.83, 8.25, 8.66, 2.66, 3.33, 6.5, 6.75, 3.66, 4.25, 4.66, 
                                                                5.16, 5.58, 2.41, 1.91, 2.08, 2.66, 3.16, 3.58, 4, 4.5, 5.25, 
                                                                5.5, 5.91, 5.41, 6, 6.5, 7, 4.08, 4.66, 5.16, 5.58, 5.91, 6, 
                                                                6.33, 1.58, 2.16, 2.58, 4.33, 4.58, 5, 5.58, 6, 6.41, 6.91, 6.58, 
                                                                7.33, 5.41, 6.08, 6.33, 6.83, 2.83, 3, 1.08, 1.66, 2.16, 3, 3.5, 
                                                                4.58, 5.16, 3.75, 4.33, 4.66, 5.16, 5.66), y = c(68, 71, 51, 
                                                                                                                 61, 63, 72, 69, 69, 72, 71, 46, 49, 64, 24, 31, 33, 39, 43, 57, 
                                                                                                                 58, 38, 59, 63, 64, 64, 50, 65, 66, 71, 55, 63, 56, 62, 26, 30, 
                                                                                                                 39, 46, 39, 48, 49, 50, 57, 63, 67, 73, 78, 78, 91, 83, 74, 78, 
                                                                                                                 71, 77, 76, 71, 63, 56, 62, 66, 62, 69, 17, 29, 42, 63, 67, 66, 
                                                                                                                 71, 71, 70, 71, 77, 79, 19, 34, 38, 40, 50, 72, 78, 33, 44, 55, 
                                                                                                                 67, 53, 66, 70, 75, 71, 72, 81, 81, 68, 63, 70, 58, 77, 79, 39, 
                                                                                                                 81, 71, 67, 49, 54, 65, 73, 72, 78, 79, 77, 84, 60, 63, 62, 61, 
                                                                                                                 67, 62, 68, 77, 65, 65, 53, 68, 68, 70, 59, 76, 50, 62, 48, 58, 
                                                                                                                 51, 63, 62, 62, 67, 56, 65, 65, 71, 70, 71, 74, 76, 79, 70, 62, 
                                                                                                                 59, 64, 64, 68, 77, 13, 25, 31, 31, 34, 57, 67, 76, 80, 82, 54, 
                                                                                                                 62, 56, 56, 58, 64, 71, 75, 92, 92, 61, 66, 53, 72, 81, 81, 59, 
                                                                                                                 59, 65, 69, 71, 68, 65, 33, 36, 34, 37, 37, 51, 53, 58, 60, 58, 
                                                                                                                 22, 91, 90, 88, 61, 59, 73, 76, 81, 67, 72, 64, 77, 31, 48, 57, 
                                                                                                                 61, 72, 61, 64, 68, 82, 61, 65, 63, 59, 66, 90, 62, 63, 67, 56, 
                                                                                                                 58, 67, 62, 69, 60, 61, 61, 67, 84, 56, 58, 63, 62, 72, 56, 53, 
                                                                                                                 47, 57, 58, 49, 63, 63, 50, 68, 71, 46, 55, 59, 62, 59, 56, 54, 
                                                                                                                 69, 67, 62, 66, 60, 65, 70, 41, 51, 48, 63, 61, 60, 59, 74, 76, 
                                                                                                                 81, 84, 86, 84, 57, 58, 30, 38, 48, 48, 61, 60, 43, 70, 70, 74, 
                                                                                                                 74, 81)), row.names = c(NA, -293L), class = "data.frame")

# define model and loop parameters
model_formula <- formula(y ~ int + (capac - int) * (1 - exp(-x * grow)))
model_starting_params <- c(int=10.876, capac=75.119, grow=0.402)
num_tries <- 100
rng_seed <- 10
# initialize vector in which to record convergence success/failure
attempt_successes <- rep(NA, num_tries)

options(warn=2)   # promote warnings to errors
for(next_attempt_num in 1:num_tries) {
  print(paste0(next_attempt_num, " / ", num_tries, "..."))
  set.seed(rng_seed)   # set random seed
  model_success <- 0
  tryCatch(   # attempt to fit model
    {
      nlme_model <- nlme(
        model_formula,
        data   = reprex_data,
        fixed  = list(int + capac + grow ~ 1),
        random = int + capac ~ 1,
        groups = ~ id,
        start  = model_starting_params,
        control = nlmeControl(maxIter=200, msMaxIter=200)
      )
      model_success <- 1      
    }, error=function(cond) {}   # catch error and keep going
  )
  attempt_successes[next_attempt_num] <- model_success   # record success/failure
}
options(warn=0)   # revert to normal warning behavior

mean(attempt_successes)   # if all values are the same, will equal either 0 or 1
```

In case it's useful, here are my R/package versions:

> R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
> (64-bit) Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6
>
> Matrix products: default LAPACK:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale: [1]
> en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] nlme_3.1-162
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_4.1.2
> tools_4.1.2     grid_4.1.2      lattice_0.20-45

My question is: Is it possible to ensure that fitting the same nlme() model multiple times will yield identical results? If so, how?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23); Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit); Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. nlme_3.1-162. I get all zeros as results. Perhaps updating nlme? (One should always report numerical instabilities using the most recent version of a package.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I just updated to nlme_3.1-162 and got 1/50 successes. I'll update the text to reflect the updated package numbers.

Comment: Maybe a Mac thing? There's a mailing list for such questions. I just tried it on a MacAir running Monterey and get all 0's. So it's _your_ Mac's behavior while running an out-of-date version of R.

Comment: Huh, thanks for the data points on both OSes. (I doubled the number of iterations in the reprex code in case the issue was that a ~4% chance of success was too low to reliably observe a success within 50 iterations.) I'll try it on an up-to-date version of R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [@IRTFM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/irtfm)'s suggestion, I updated R to the most current version (4.2.2), which solved the problem. nlme() models now consistently converge, or consistently fail to converge, with a given random seed (and are also more consistent across seeds). A good reminder to stay updated!